# IIS WCAT toolkit

Tags: iis

Where can we download the WCAT toolkit. There seems to be many versions of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official one is 6.3. It's dated 11/6/2008 and supports IIS versions 5.1 through 7. You can find it at http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1466&g=6.